# how to install phonegapbuildapi on mac

Tags: node.js

while installing i get this errors... how to install it? can anyone help me??

```
localhost:~ rammanikannta$ git clone git://github.com/germallon/phonegapbuildapi.git 
Cloning into 'phonegapbuildapi'...
remote: Counting objects: 190, done.    
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (89/89), done.    
remote: Total 190 (delta 106), reused 180 (delta 97)    
Receiving objects: 100% (190/190), 59.61 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.    
Resolving deltas: 100% (106/106), done.    
Checking connectivity... done    

localhost:~ rammanikannta$ cd phonegapbuildapi    

localhost:phonegapbuildapi rammanikannta$ npm link    
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '/Users/rammanikannta/phonegapbuildapi'    
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, symlink '/Users/rammanikannta/phonegapbuildapi']    
npm ERR!   errno: 3,    
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',    
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/rammanikannta/phonegapbuildapi' }    
npm ERR!     
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.    
npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0    
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "link"    
npm ERR! cwd /Users/rammanikannta/phonegapbuildapi    
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.20    
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11    
npm ERR! path /Users/rammanikannta/phonegapbuildapi    
npm ERR! code EACCES    
npm ERR! errno 3    
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, symlink '/Users/rammanikannta/phonegapbuildapi'    
npm ERR!     
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:    
npm ERR!     /Users/rammanikannta/phonegapbuildapi/npm-debug.log    
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: this is where i tried to install phonegapbuildapi from     https://github.com/germallon/phonegapbuildapi

Answer (score 0):

See that: `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`
try `sudo npm link`

Answer (score 0):

Run the `npm link` command as root:

```
$ sudo npm link
```

(assuming that user `rammanikannta` is an administrator).

When asked for a password, enter your own.

The reason for this is that `npm link` tries to create a symlink from the global `node_modules` directory to your downloaded `phonegapbuildapi`, and you probably don't have the correct rights to create that symlink.

Comment: Thank you for the response @robertklep it actually worked... but the problem is that it doesnt install phonegapbuildapi completely... when i run anything from terminal it displays the following errors:

Comment: localhost:node rammanikannta$ node CreateFileBasedApp.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'phonegapbuildapi'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rammanikannta/node/CreateFileBasedApp.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

Comment: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

Comment: @user2848995 try setting the `NODE_PATH` environment variable: `NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH`

Comment: @user2848995 in your shell: `NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH node CreateFileBasedApp.js` (as one line)